# Set Visibility Of Android Menu Item Outside of onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm checking if user is admin result from Firestore as async then showing a button if admin. I need to **set visibility of a button in the menu outside onPrepareOptionsMenu** like inside another function, how can i do it?

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val menuitem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_edit_product)
        if (menuitem != null) { //null check
            menuitem.setVisible(false) //hide the item
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do it inside the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method?

Comment: because firestore result is async and it's loaded after onPrepareOptionsMenu so my value is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

#### Use `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` anyway

This is what I'd recommend. In whatever async callback you're using, modify the value of a `Boolean` flag or other similar logic, and then call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, which will trigger `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` whenever you want:

```
private var showItem = false

fun example() {
    doAsync { resultCode -> 
        showItem = (resultCode == 200)
        invalidateOptionsMenu()
    }
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val menuitem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_edit_product)
    if (menuitem != null) {
        menuitem.setVisible(showItem) // reference the flag here
    }
    return true
}
```

#### Store the `MenuItem`s when you create them

It is valid to save references to `MenuItem` objects generated in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. You could save the item off at that time and then update it directly from your async callback:

```
private lateinit var menuitem: MenuItem

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    this.menuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit_product)
    return true
}

fun example() {
    doAsync { resultCode -> 
        menuitem.setVisible(resultCode == 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, store menuitem is suitable and works for me.